# Trying to simplify a Boolean expression to \$X + Y + Z\$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Problem:

Prove the following Boolean equation using algebraic manipulations:

$$ Y + \overline X Z + X \overline Y = X + Y + Z $$

Answer:

$$LHS = Y + \overline X Z + X \overline Y$$
\begin{align*}
LHS &= Y + X \overline Y + \overline X Z  \\
LHS &= Y( 1 + X ) + \overline X Z  \\
LHS &= Y + \overline X Z  \\
\end{align*}

I cannot reduce the expression to X + Y+Z.

I think there
is a mistake in the problem.

Consider the following values:

\begin{align*}
X &= 1 \\
Y &= 1 \\
Z &= 0
\end{align*}

In this case, I claim the value
of the left hand side is 0 but the value of the right hand side is 1. Therefore, the identity is false. Do I have this right?

Comment: The left hand side contains Y, so if Y=1, the left hand side must be1.

Comment: Your counterexample is wrong. With Y=1 both sides are 1 anyway.

Comment: As a general method, when in doubt, to check if such problems are correct in the first place, I'd compute the truth table of both sides and see if they match.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a pure math question and should be asked on the relevant math community instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below you can find the steps I took to reach the answer in the solution. I think you made a mistake in your second step.

[image]

Comment: Please don't give out solutions to homework problems. We prefer to give the OP hints and guide them to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am not currently taking any classes and I do not plan to take any classes. Therefore, I do not consider this to be a homework problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake isn't in the problem, it is in your attempted solution - more specifically, after this step:

$$LHS=Y+X\overline Y + \overline X Z$$

You deduced that:

$$LHS=Y(1+X)+\overline XZ$$

Note that the above implies that:
$$Y+X\overline Y=Y+XY$$

Which is clearly false.

The easiest way to simplify the following expression, in my opinion, would be using a [K-Map](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/karnaugh-map-boolean-algebraic-simplification-technique/). If you insist on proving the equality using the algebraic method, review [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and try to apply them on the given expression.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another proof...

Note that for any \$X\$ and \$Y\$:

$$
\begin{align}
    X+Y &= X(Y+\bar{Y}) + Y(X+\bar{X}) \\
        &= XY + X\bar{Y} + XY + \bar{X}Y \\
        &= XY + X\bar{Y} + \bar{X}Y \\
        &= X(Y+\bar{Y}) + \bar{X}Y \\
        &= X + \bar{X}Y \\
\end{align}
$$

Now apply this formula twice, first with \$Y\$ and \$X\$ and then with the pair \$X\$ and \$Z\$:
$$
\begin{align}
    Y + X\bar{Y} + \bar{X}Z &= Y + X + \bar{X}Z \\
                            &= Y + X + Z \\
\end{align}
$$